# Does Orchard have Active Directory authentication?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication

I've been looking over the Orchard CMS and it seems like a capable CMS and mature enough to do what we need here. However, one thing I haven't been able to find info on is AD authentication. We plan to use it as a Intranet page and wiki. Since all the users use .NET/AD for everything, I was hoping that Orchard would automatically have AD authentication functionality built-in or available. However, I haven't found any info on it.

So does anyone have any idea whether Orchard handles AD auth out-the-box, through a plugin/module, or sometime in the future?

Answer (score 4):

You may find this discussion on the Orchard codeplex site useful:

http://orchard.codeplex.com/discussions/230525#post506416

> ...here's a working AutoLoginController for those that are interested. It uses Active Directory...